# Setting the Datepicker in IOS to pick only the Day and month

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uidatepicker

I want to set the datepicker in XCode-Interface Builder to just use the rollers of the "day" and "month"? I've search, but everyone want to keep month and year but not the day.
I know that we could set the datePicker Mode to "date" but the year appear. So, do you know how we could implement this ?
Another problem, i want to show the day name in my textField, i don't know how we can make that.

my text field is like that :

Monday 1 june

Comment: for displaying your date in your textfield use `NSDateFormatter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIDatePicker` doesn't support this. You will need to use `UIPickerView` and add whatever components you need with whatever values should be shown.

To format the date in your text field, use an `NSDateFormatter` to format the date as needed.

Comment: If you're going to build your own picker you'll probably need an array of localized month names. NSDateFormatter includes a method, monthSymbols, that you can use to get the list of month names. There is also a method weekdaySymbols.

Comment: Ok for the UIPickerView. It is possible to have more informations about the NSDateFormatter because i use that for display the date and the month, but i don't know how display the date name. If you can show me an example it will be perfect.

Comment: What is "date name"? Do you mean the weekday? Read the docs for `NSDateFormatter`. Follow the links that describe for various format specifiers.